# pcd file failed

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to use Autoware to map a large area ( bag file of 5.3 GB). After the mapping has been done, i output the pcd map according to https://github.com/autowarefoundation/autoware/issues/1207?source=post_page---------------------------

After i output the map, when i tried using the .pcd file in the map tab, on the console it said "failed "Path_to_pcd_file"" and only map a part of the map that were supposed to be created. Has anybody had this problem before and if so how do i fix it?
I suspect that it is because the output map is quite large (253.MB), as i was trying to map with smaller maps before and autoware worked fine.

Thanks in advance

---

Update:

For the pcd file, you can find it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mZaWlnoxCkZJBvKCnlMGvePOl3nCk2YU/view?usp=drivesdk)
I am using:

- autoware 1.10.0
- Ubuntu 16.04

I installed ros from source, following the instruction in this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Ubuntu) and i am not using docker.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329270/pcd-file-failed/) by [hoang khac](https://answers.ros.org/users/44267/hoang-khac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yamato Ando](https://answers.ros.org/users/43573/yamato-ando/) on 2019-07-26**:
Would you please share a screenshot of the console showing the error?
And if possible, please share your .pcd file.

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-07-26**:
We also need to know which version of Autoware you are using, what version of Ubuntu, how you installed ROS (source or from `apt`), and whether or not you are using Docker.

**Comment by [hoang khac](https://answers.ros.org/users/44267/hoang-khac/) on 2019-07-26**:
Hi,
Thank you all for answering to my question. I am very new to this so excuse me for the newbie's mistake
For the pcd file, you can find it on https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mZaWlnoxCkZJBvKCnlMGvePOl3nCk2YU/view?usp=drivesdk
I am using autoware 1.10.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. I installed ros from source, following the instruction in this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Ubuntu) and i am not using docker.
Unfortunately, i am not with my laptop at the moment and can not provide the console of the error.
I really do appreciate if anybody has any advices.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-07-26**:
@hoang khac I've edited your question to include the information from your comment so that it's easier to find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for sharing PCD.

It seems that the number of point clouds written in the header of the file is different.
Please open autowre-190725.pcd with an editor and rewrite WIDTH and POINTS from 35006911 to 8080162.

---

Originally posted by [Yamato Ando](https://answers.ros.org/users/43573/yamato-ando/) with karma: 231 on 2019-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hoang khac](https://answers.ros.org/users/44267/hoang-khac/) on 2019-07-27**:
Thank you very much i will try that once i get back

**Comment by [hoang khac](https://answers.ros.org/users/44267/hoang-khac/) on 2019-07-31**:
Thank you so much. It now has worked output the correct answers.